# Pluralization bug: "1 answers" in the Hot Questions list

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, plurals

I was browsing the [Hot Questions list](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), and this caught my eye:

[image: Image of the HNQ list, with the "1 answers" parts circled in red pen]

For the top and bottom questions, which both have a single answer, it should say “1 answer”, not “1 answers”.