# Pluralization issue in the tags page tooltip for "1 questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tooltips, plurals

There is a pluralization issue in the [Tags page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags?page=5&tab=popular).
When there is only one question was asked for the tag in the recent time, it is showing as

> 1 question**s** tagged <tagname> in the last <period>

It should be displayed as "1 question tagged <tagname> in the last <period>"

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Tags page]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed.

> "Pluralization"
> is hard to use in haiku
> syllables galore

Comment: Could [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB35Q.png) also be fixed? =(

Comment: @Ak. you mean [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360772/pluralization-issue-when-only-one-more-comment-is-to-be-shown-show-1-more-comm) one?

Comment: @Ollie Yup! I've seen your post already. There was no further action on that, so I commented here.

Comment: @Ak. there's a planned tag on it now ;)

Comment: Yeah! =) @Ollie

Comment: What about [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255959/pluralisation-bug-1-answers-in-the-hot-questions-list) from 2015?